# Disabling Android auto-complete filtering

Tags: android, autocomplete, textview

I have a simple `AutoCompleteTextView` and I have added a custom `ArrayAdapter` to it. Whenever user types a character, I dynamically update my `autoCompleteAdapter` from a remote service. Here is the related part of my code that initializes the mechanism:

```
    autoCompleteAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<MyObjectType>(this,
        android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);
    autoCompleteAdapter.setNotifyOnChange(true);

    myInput.setAdapter(autoCompleteAdapter);
    myInput.setThreshold(MIN_SUGGEST_LEN);
```

It works without any problem. But `ArrayAdapter` filters the items that is shown on dropdown list according to user input. However sometimes my sugestions does not match with user's input, so I maintain suggestion list (i.e. `autoCompleteAdapter`) manualy. How can I disable adapter filtering so that all the items in `autoCompleteAdapater` is shown on dropdown list regardless of the user's input?